# Minecraft 1.9+ mob spawner set to not spawn entities

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can use /setblock to create a mob_spawner but I want to set a mob_spawner without it actually spawning any entities, just for display in a shop, yet I can't find out how to do that.

Comment: Do you want to see the entity inside the spawner, or for it to be blank? Do you want the flame particles and spinning animation to continue?

Comment: Yes I would like the entity inside the spawner but no flame particles, spinning animation can be on or off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting the spawner's `MaxNearbyEntities`:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ mob_spawner 0 replace {MaxNearbyEntities:0}
```

Comment: Got what I needed from this, thank here is the end results...

Comment: /setblock ~2 ~ ~ mob_spawner 0 replace {MaxNearbyEntities:0,SpawnPotentials:[{SpawnCount:"0",Entity:{id:"Cave_spider"}}]}

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing you could try is just having the mob spawner there and then behind
it place a repeating command block behind it (make sure players cant see it) that has the following command:

/kill @e[type=Pig,r=10]

this command block is killing any pigs that come withing a 10 block radius of it

please note that if you chose this path you must be precise with the entity name
for it, for example if you do /kill @e[type=pig] (with no capital p) it will go on a constant loop killing you. if this happens simply go to your properties file and disable command blocks, restart , destroy the command block turn command block back on restart again and your good
hope this helps :D

Comment: I will give that a try if all else fails, thank you!

Comment: Near the spawner, you would be able to see/hear pigs dying, and you could collect their drops. I don't think this is the solution you want.